# How does one use SwiftUI's ToolbarItemGroup?

Tags: swiftui

I clear don't understand the meaning of the definition syntax for SwiftUI because I can't figure out how one would use ToolbarItemGroup.

I can define a toolbar with toolbar items like this:

```
.toolbar {
            
            ToolbarItem {
                Button("200%", action: zoom200).foregroundColor(controller.scale == 2.0 ? selectedButtonColor : defaultButtonColor)
            }
            ToolbarItem {
                Button("100%", action: zoom100).foregroundColor(controller.scale == 1.0 ? selectedButtonColor : defaultButtonColor)
            }
}
```

But have been unable to get ToolbarItemGroup to work.  Logically I would have expected something like this:

```
.toolbar {
   ToolbarItemGroup {
            
         ToolbarItem {
                Button("200%", action: zoom200).foregroundColor(controller.scale == 2.0 ? selectedButtonColor : defaultButtonColor)
            }
         ToolbarItem {
                Button("100%", action: zoom100).foregroundColor(controller.scale == 1.0 ? selectedButtonColor : defaultButtonColor)
            }
   }
   ToolbarItemGroup {
         ToolbarItem {
                Button("Open", action: open)
            }
         ToolbarItem {
                Button("Close", action: close)
            }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `ToolbarItemGroup` is output entity, not input - as it is clear from the following `toolbar` builders:

```
/// Populates the toolbar or navigation bar with the specified items.
///
/// - Parameter items: The items representing the content of the toolbar.
public func toolbar<Items>(@ToolbarContentBuilder<Void> items: () -> ToolbarItemGroup<Void, Items>) -> some View


/// Populates the toolbar or navigation bar with the specified items,
/// allowing for user customization.
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - id: A unique identifier for this toolbar.
///   - items: The items representing the content of the toolbar.
public func toolbar<Items>(id: String, @ToolbarContentBuilder<String> items: () -> ToolbarItemGroup<String, Items>) -> some View
```

Thus groups are generated automatically by `.toolbar` based on toolbar items placement (in predefined order).

Here is example (tested with Xcode 12b / iOS 14)

[image: demo]

```
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
        Button(action: {}) { Image(systemName: "book") }
    }
    ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
        Button(action: {}) { Image(systemName: "gear") }
    }
    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
        Button(action: {}) { Image(systemName: "car") }
    }
    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
        Button(action: {}) { Image(systemName: "gear") }
    }
    ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
        Button(action: {}) { Image(systemName: "1.square") }
    }
    ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) {
        Button(action: {}) { Image(systemName: "2.square") }
    }
}
```

Comment: Trust me nothing is clear from those constructors - there needs to be a tutorial on constructor language !!  We're heading down the Windows path now with too many API's and half of them half baked and lack of adequate documentation.  This is how Rome collapsed.

Comment: With Beta 5 this no longer works.  Your gear icon from `.primaryAction` won't appear.

Comment: @Gargoyle, just retested with 12b5 - works fine. Post a question with your code and we'll see what's going on.

Comment: I just copied your code directly.  Notice how you specify six icons, above, but you only have 5 in the picture. When I ran that with b5 I only had 4 appear.

Comment: This does work on iPad and iPhone/landscape but it does not work on iPhone/portrait. Documentation of `ToolbarItemPlacement` says: "In compact horizontal size classes, the system limits both the leading and the trailing positions of the navigation bar to a single item each."

Comment: @Gargoyle I don't believe duplicates show up.

Answer (score 30):

[ToolbarItemGroup](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/toolbaritemgroup) is designed to group views in the same toolbar. It removes the need for explicit usage of [ToolbarItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/toolbaritem), as both conform to [ToolbarContent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/toolbarcontent).

e.g.

```swift
.toolbar {
  ToolbarItemGroup {
    Button("200%",  action: zoom200)
      .foregroundColor(controller.scale == 2.0 ? selectedButtonColor : defaultButtonColor)
    Button("100%", action: zoom100)
      .foregroundColor(controller.scale == 1.0 ? selectedButtonColor : defaultButtonColor)
  }
  ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {
    Spacer()
    Button("Open", action: open)
    Spacer()
    Button("Close", action: close)
    Spacer()
  }
}
```

It's also the only way I know of to get `Spacer`s to work, between toolbar items.

Comment: One can also use separately wrapped `Spacer()` like this

`ToolbarItem(placement: .bottomBar) { Spacer() }`