# Replacement for .navigationBarItems SwiftUI view modifier

Tags: swift, swiftui

[.navigationBarItems](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/navigationbaritems(leading:trailing:)) is deprecated. Exists a replacement for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is `.toolbar` modifier with group of one or more `ToolbarItem` elements in it.

See the demo in my other post [How does one use SwiftUI's ToolbarItemGroup?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62692449/12299030) for example of usage.