# Spacer() doesn't work properly in .toolbar

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I've encountered the following issue with a .toolbar in NavigationView. It seems Spacer() doesn't work properly there. Here's a screenshot [Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jquzw.jpg)

And here's the code

```
NavigationView {
        ...
        .toolbar {
            // bottom
            ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {
                HStack {
                    NavigationLink {
                        ...SomeView...
                    } label: {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
                            Text("Contacts")
                        }
                    }.padding()
                    Spacer()
                    NavigationLink {
                        ...SomeView...
                    } label: {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: "message.fill")
                            Text("Chats")
                        }
                    }.padding()
                    Spacer()
                    NavigationLink {
                        ...SomeView...
                    } label: {
                        VStack {
                            Image(systemName: "pencil.circle")
                            Text("Settings")
                        }
                    }.padding()
                }
                .font(.caption)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
        }
```

Interestingly enough, it start working when I'm switching to another view (using NavigationLink), and then go back.

Another note that it shown correctly in preview in xcode, but behave differently on the phone (iPhone 12, iOS 15.4)

Comment: Did you try remove all ``Spacer()`` because you already have ``HStack`` handle list button

Comment: @bewithyou I did, it becomes more tight on the preview, but nothing changes when reviewing on the phone, it's still left-aligned

Comment: Did you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62690819/how-does-one-use-swiftuis-toolbaritemgroup) ?